# multi dimensional array in random order

Tags: php

I want to make it so that my multi dimensional array is in a random order. How would you do it?

```
// This is how the array looks like
print_r($slides);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [status] => 1
            [sortorder] => 0
            [title] => Pants
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [status] => 1
            [sortorder] => 0
            [title] => Jewels
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [status] => 1
            [sortorder] => 0
            [title] => Birdhouse
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [status] => 1
            [sortorder] => 0
            [title] => Shirt
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [status] => 1
            [sortorder] => 0
            [title] => Phone
        )

)

// This how the result is if I use array_rand()
print_r(array_rand($slides, 5));

Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)

// This how the result is if I use shuffle()
print_r(shuffle($slides));

1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shuffling the first level of the array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758260/shuffling-the-first-level-of-the-array-in-php)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`shuffle()` is the way to go here. It prints `1` because `shuffle` changes the array **in-place** and returns a boolean, as it is written in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php):

> Returns **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on failure.

I suggest to also read the [documentation of `array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

> Picks one or more random entries out of an array, **and returns the key (or keys)** of the random entries.

---

Always read documentation if you use built-in functions. Don't just *assume* how the work. I bet it took more time to write the question than looking this up.

Comment: Up vote on "Don't just assume how they work" because php functions are inconsistent as hell :)

Comment: *Palm to head* Of course! I misunderstod the explanation at php.net for shuffle()

Comment: I feel like this is a dumb comment but I assume "shirt" wants to maintain its "status" after the shuffle.  In other words, only the first dimension get shuffled, right?

Comment: While print_r works in the class room, in real world, when you need to use echo, use $slides[0][1]. One (1) is the part of the array to return. This is not obvious in the PHP manual. In other words, you wish to echo the first array (0) and the part needed

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
print_r(shuffle($slides));
```

do

```
shuffle($slides);
print_r($slides);
```

You see [`shuffle()`](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) shuffles the array in-place

Comment: Thanks for all the downvotes. A comment on what's wrong would be nice though

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure how you want it to display but you can loop the array and use php rand(0,arraylen) function to parse the array.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfect. print_r(shuffle($slides))) gives the output of TRUE, since the return value of `shuffle` is a boolean and not an array.

See the working example here: http://codepad.org/B5SlcjGf