# PHP Randomly select an array from an multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this array of objects. From which I want to take at random one of the objects from the array, and use it for its intended purpose. I have tried `array_rand()` but that only returned a random value from one of the arrays within. Is there a method similar to `array_rand()` that will let me use the whole array as the variable rather than a value pluked from within it?

Example Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10003
            [state] => CA
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10003
            [state] => CA
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10006
            [state] => CA
        )
)
```

What I want to do when doing something similar to `array_rand()` is end up with a variable that is

```
[0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 10006
                [state] => CA
            )
```

or similar

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `array_rand`? what you want is `$yourArray[array_rand($yourArray)];`

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355154/multi-dimensional-array-in-random-order

Comment: @7-isnotbad I wouldn't say it's quite a duplicate. While there's a bunch of useful information in the question you've linked, shuffling the array might not be the best way of getting a single random value

Comment: THere's lots of dupes, that first isn't one. [This is more to the point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233407/get-random-item-from-array/4233416#4233416). There's no difference in getting a random scalar from an array to getting a random complex variable, an array entry is an array entry, doesn't matter what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [array_rand documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

> [array_rand] picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the
>   **key (or keys)** of the random entries.

To summarize: if you want to retrieve a random *value* from an array, you need to use the random *key* provided by `array_rand` to access it.

Solution, assuming your array is stored in `$obj`:

```
$random_obj = $obj[array_rand($obj));
```