# Shuffling the first level of the array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

PHP's `shuffle()` is not randomizing an array the way I need it. I have a two dimensional array and when I use `shuffle()` on it it only randomizes the 2nd dimension of the array, but I need the opposite.

Lets assume this is the array I need to shuffle:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 199
            [key2] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 195
            [key2] => 3
        )

)
```

The way the `shuffle()` shuffles it is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 195
            [key2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 199
            [key2] => 6
        )

)
```

But this is not what I'm after. What I need as an end result is this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 195
            [key2] => 6
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 199
            [key2] => 6
        )

)
```

I know that this can be achieved this using a random key with `rand()` or `mt_rand()`, but it also could be possible that for a small amount of keys, we could receive the same `rand()` key twice, leading to NOT have a nicely shuffled array.

I also know that adding more `if else` logic would be a possibility, but I'm looking to do this with already implemented stuff - I don't wanna reinvent the wheel.

How can I achieve my desired shuffle?

Comment: `shuffle()` isn't recursive.  How are you using it?  Can you show your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [multi dimensional array in random order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355154/multi-dimensional-array-in-random-order)

Comment: `shuffle()` is working as intended.  The issue is probably (from the docs http://php.net/shuffle): `Note: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just reordering the keys.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shuffle()` is working as intended.  It is not "randomizing the 2nd dimension", it is not recursive.

It is reordering the elements of the array (which just happen to be arrays).  The issue you are seeing is because `shuffle()` resets the array's keys.

From the docs (http://php.net/shuffle):

> **Note**: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than
>   just reordering the keys.

To get what you want, you need to use `array_rand()` to randomize the keys, then reorder the elements in the array based on that.

```
$randKeys = array_rand($array, count($array));
// This is needed because array_rand was changed
// and now returns the keys in order
shuffle($randKeys);

uksort($array, function($a, $b) use($randKeys){
    return array_search($a, $randKeys) - array_search($b, $randKeys);
});
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/101265

Comment: +1 Works; trying now to put this into a function, but doesn't work that way. How would this be formulated where i can simply pass in the array to a function?

Comment: You need to make your function takes its parameter as a reference.  `function myFunc(&$array){}`

Answer (score 0):

In the comment section of the PHP manual for shuffle you find:

```
<?php
function shuffle_assoc(&$array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    shuffle($keys);

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $new[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    $array = $new;

    return true;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourArray = array(
    array('key1' => 199, 'key2' => 6),
    array('key1' => 195, 'key2' => 3),
    array('key1' => 205, 'key2' => 8)
);

$helperArr = array();
foreach($yourArray as $subArr)
{
    foreach($subArr as $key => $value)
        $helperArr[$key][] = $value;        
}

foreach($helperArr as &$shuffleArr)
    shuffle($shuffleArr);

$shuffledArr = array();
foreach($helperArr as $key => $value)
{   
    for($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++)
        $shuffledArr[$i][$key] = $value[$i];        
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($helperArr);
print_r($shuffledArr);
echo '</pre>';
```

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0pu-5vf)

Comment: I don't think this is what he is looking for.